# How to change logo and css style in vtiger crm login page?

Tags: php, vtiger

How to change logo and css style in vtiger crm login page? Where is file with this?
I tried to find but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Logo

Go to test->logo->vtiger-crm-logo.gif

Paste your logo their and rename it with "vtiger-crm-logo.gif".

Or to change login page logo go to smarty->templates->Login.tpl and at line no 16(near about) place the address of your image.

And For CSS

Go to themes->Softed (your themes name) (by default theme)->style.css.